# CEF borderless window handling renderer's WM_NCHITTEST messages

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, chromium-embedded, borderless

I created a CEF browser within a borderless window (WS_POPUP style).
The CEF renderer overlaps my window's client area.

The problem is that I'd like to allow the user to resize the window but I can't 
handle the WM_NCHITTEST message.

I found many topics on the Internet but there was no actual solution.

Of course, I could create a 1px border with WM_NCCALCSIZE but I don't want to, as I would need to change the color of the border depending on the browser's content.

Is there a way to subclass the renderer's window (used internally by CEF)?
Do I really need to handle the WM_NCHITTEST message? Is there another way of doing that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
winapiwrapper